# Second partial derivative of $f(ax+by)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I stumbled across this result:

$$f_{xx}(ax+by) = \frac{a}{b} f_{xy}(ax+by)$$

Which I can't off the top of my head justify... I'm sure it's a very simple property but I can't seem to be able to convince myself of it. How would one go about showing this? Assume $f$ is $C^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming $f$ is twice differentiable one has
$$f_{x}(ax+by)=f'(ax+by)\cdot a$$
Differentiating one more time wrt $x$ yields
$$f_{xx}(ax+by)=f''(ax+by)\cdot a^2$$
Now we differentiate with respect to $y$ to get
$$f_{xy}(ax+by)=f''(ax+by)\cdot ab$$
Therefore 
$$\frac{1}{a^2}f_{xx}(ax+by)=\frac{1}{ab}f_{xy}(ax+by)$$
The result follows.

Comment: Of course! Thanks. I managed to recover the result by just expanding $f$ in a power series in $(ax+by)$ and differentiating that.